# What is the best way to modify a list in a 'foreach' loop?

Tags: c#, .net, list, enumeration, enumerable

A new feature in C# / .NET 4.0 is that you can change your enumerable in a `foreach` without getting the exception. See Paul Jackson's blog entry *[An Interesting Side-Effect of Concurrency: Removing Items from a Collection While Enumerating](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308065012/www.lovethedot.net/2009/03/interesting-side-effect-of-concurrency.html)* for information on this change.

What is the best way to do the following?

```
foreach(var item in Enumerable)
{
    foreach(var item2 in item.Enumerable)
    {
        item.Add(new item2)
    }
}
```

Usually I use an `IList` as a cache/buffer until the end of the `foreach`, but is there better way?

Comment: Hmm..  Can you point us to documentation of this change?   Enumerables have always been immutable when enumerating over the collection.

Comment: This is a variation on the theme that prompted Steve McConnell to advise [never to monkey with the loop index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457036/dont-monkey-with-the-loop-index).

Comment: I know I'm digging up a very old conversation here, but I'd be extremely careful with this. Only the new concurrent collections are modifiable within foreach - all the previous collection types, and I imagine the majority of future collection types too, will still be immutable while enumerating over them. Making extensive use of this quirk would effectively lock you into using the concurrent collections, because if you wanted to use a different collection in the future all of your quirky foreach loops would suddenly break.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Don't monkey with the loop index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457036/c-sharp-dont-monkey-with-the-loop-index)

Comment: Is this question asking specifically about the concurrent collections? Or is it asking a more general question and mentioning that only for contrast?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The collection used in foreach is immutable. This is very much by design.

As it says on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

> The foreach statement is used to
>   iterate through the collection to get
>   the information that you want, but can
>   not be used to add or remove items
>   from the source collection to avoid
>   unpredictable side effects. **If you
>   need to add or remove items from the
>   source collection, use a for loop.**

The post in the [link](http://www.lovethedot.net/2009/03/interesting-side-effect-of-concurrency.html) provided by Poko indicates that this is allowed in the new concurrent collections.

Comment: You're answer doesn't really answer the question. He knows that the basic foreach loop is immutable... he wants to know the best way to apply changes to an enumerable collection.

Comment: Then the answer is: use a regular for-loop, as suggested in the quote.  I am aware that the OP mentions this behavior changes in C# 4.0, but I can't find any information on that. For now, I think this is still a relevant answer.

Answer (score 15):

Make a copy of the enumeration, using an IEnumerable extension method in this case, and enumerate over it.  This would add a copy of every element in every inner enumerable to that enumeration.

```
foreach(var item in Enumerable)
{
    foreach(var item2 in item.Enumerable.ToList())
    {
        item.Add(item2)
    }
}
```

Comment: But why copy the enumerable to a list instead of an array? A list provides methods to search, sort and manipulate the collection, which we don't need.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! rather person who says it's not possible in answer is marked as answer!

Answer (score 13):

To illustrate Nippysaurus's answer: If you are going to **add** the new items to the list and want to process the newly added items too during the same enumeration then you can just use **for** loop instead of **foreach** loop, problem solved :)

```
var list = new List<YourData>();
... populate the list ...

//foreach (var entryToProcess in list)
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var entryToProcess = list[i];

    var resultOfProcessing = DoStuffToEntry(entryToProcess);

    if (... condition ...)
        list.Add(new YourData(...));
}
```

For runnable example:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        list.Add(i);

    //foreach (var entry in list)
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var entry = list[i];
        if (entry % 2 == 0)
            list.Add(entry + 1);

        Console.Write(entry + ", ");
    }

    Console.Write(list);
}
```

Output of last example:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,

List (15 items) 

0 

1 

2 

3 

4 

5 

6 

7 

8 

9 

1 

3 

5 

7 

9

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned, but with a code sample:

```
foreach(var item in collection.ToArray())
    collection.Add(new Item...);
```

Comment: This isn't a great answer because it performs unnecessary allocations and copies (`ToArray()`) just to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 5):

You should really use `for()` instead of `foreach()` in this case.

Comment: That will potentially clutter code with one more variable which will hold the original number of elements in collection.

Comment: If you are changing the length of the collection, then you want your for loop to be evaluated against the new length, not the original or you could get an out of range exception

Comment: @Anton: You will *need* that extra variable, because you'll have to manage the iteration yourself when the collection is modified

Comment: @Nippysaurus: Sounds great, and I agree with you in theory, but some collections can't be indexed. You have to iterate over them.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the enumerable collection while it is being enumerated, so you will have to make your changes before or after enumerating.

The `for` loop is a nice alternative, but if your `IEnumerable` collection does not implement `ICollection`, it is not possible.

Either:

1) Copy collection first. Enumerate the copied collection and change the original collection during the enumeration. (@tvanfosson)

or

2) Keep a list of changes and commit them after the enumeration.

Answer (score 4):

[LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) is very effective for juggling with collections.

Your types and structure are unclear to me, but I will try to fit your example to the best of my ability.

From your code it appears that, for each item, you are adding to that item everything from its own 'Enumerable' property. This is very simple:

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable)
{
    item = item.AddRange(item.Enumerable));
}
```

As a more general example, let's say we want to iterate a collection and remove items where a certain condition is true. Avoiding `foreach`, using LINQ:

```
myCollection = myCollection.Where(item => item.ShouldBeKept);
```

Add an item based on each existing item? No problem:

```
myCollection = myCollection.Concat(myCollection.Select(item => new Item(item.SomeProp)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do that (quick and dirty solution. If you *really* need this kind of behavior, you should either reconsider your design or override all `IList<T>` members and aggregate the source list):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class ModifiableList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private readonly IList<T> pendingAdditions = new List<T>();
        private int activeEnumerators = 0;

        public ModifiableList(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
        {
        }

        public ModifiableList()
        {
        }

        public new void Add(T t)
        {
            if(activeEnumerators == 0)
                base.Add(t);
            else
                pendingAdditions.Add(t);
        }

        public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            ++activeEnumerators;

            foreach(T t in ((IList<T>)this))
                yield return t;

            --activeEnumerators;

            AddRange(pendingAdditions);
            pendingAdditions.Clear();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ModifiableList<int> ints = new ModifiableList<int>(new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8 });

            foreach(int i in ints)
                ints.Add(i * 2);

            foreach(int i in ints)
                Console.WriteLine(i * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to Timo's answer LINQ can be used like this as well:

```
items = items.Select(i => {

     ...
     //perform some logic adding / updating.

     return i / return new Item();
     ...

     //To remove an item simply have logic to return null.

     //Then attach the Where to filter out nulls

     return null;
     ...


}).Where(i => i != null);
```

Comment: Upvoting, LINQ is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

The best approach from a performance perspective is probably to use a one or two arrays.  Copy the list to an array, do operations on the array, and then build a new list from the array.  Accessing an array element is faster than accessing a list item, and conversions between a `List<T>` and a `T[]` can use a fast "bulk copy" operation which avoids the overhead associated accessing individual items.

For example, suppose you have a `List<string>` and wish to have every string in the list which starts with `T` be followed by an item "Boo", while every string that starts with "U" is dropped entirely.  An optimal approach would probably be something like:

```
int srcPtr,destPtr;
string[] arr;

srcPtr = theList.Count;
arr = new string[srcPtr*2];
theList.CopyTo(arr, theList.Count); // Copy into second half of the array
destPtr = 0;
for (; srcPtr < arr.Length; srcPtr++)
{
  string st = arr[srcPtr];
  char ch = (st ?? "!")[0]; // Get first character of string, or "!" if empty
  if (ch != 'U')
    arr[destPtr++] = st;
  if (ch == 'T')
    arr[destPtr++] = "Boo";
}
if (destPtr > arr.Length/2) // More than half of dest. array is used
{
  theList = new List<String>(arr); // Adds extra elements
  if (destPtr != arr.Length)
    theList.RemoveRange(destPtr, arr.Length-destPtr); // Chop to proper length
}
else
{
  Array.Resize(ref arr, destPtr);
  theList = new List<String>(arr); // Adds extra elements
}
```

It would have been helpful if `List<T>` provided a method to construct a list from a portion of an array, but I'm unaware of any efficient method for doing so.  Still, operations on arrays are pretty fast.  Of note is the fact that adding and removing items from the list does not require "pushing" around other items; each item gets written directly to its appropriate spot in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I have written one easy step, but because of this performance will be degraded

Here is my code snippet:-

```
for (int tempReg = 0; tempReg < reg.Matches(lines).Count; tempReg++)
                            {
                                foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(lines))
                                {
                                    var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(lines);
                                    aStringBuilder.Insert(startIndex, match.ToString().Replace(",", " ");
                                    lines[k] = aStringBuilder.ToString();
                                    tempReg = 0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
```