# Does foreach() iterate by reference?

Tags: c#, reference, foreach

Consider this:

```
List<MyClass> obj_list = get_the_list();
foreach( MyClass obj in obj_list )
{
    obj.property = 42;
}
```

Is `obj` a reference to the corresponding object within the list so that when I change the property the change will persist in the object instance once constructed somewhere?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612584/update-struct-in-foreach-loop-in-c

Comment: There is `foreach (ref var x in XXX)` syntax, available since C#7.3, when `Current` property of `Enumerator` returns `ref T` (e.g. for iteration on `Span<T>`). See @Wolf's answer for details.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes, `obj` is a reference to the current object in the collection (assuming `MyClass` is in fact a class). If you change any properties via the reference, you're changing the object, just like you would expect.

Be aware however, that you cannot change the variable `obj` itself as it is the iteration variable. You'll get a compile error if you try. That means that you can't null it and if you're iterating value types, you can't modify any members as that would be changing the value.

The C# language specification states (8.8.4)

> "The iteration variable corresponds to
>   a read-only local variable with a
>   scope that extends over the embedded
>   statement."

Comment: This is true even for value types, i.e. structs.

Comment: @technophile: Actually you can't modify obj if MyClass is a struct, cause you're not allowed to modify the iteration variable itself.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: Why cant we modify the enumerable object ?

Comment: @Amy: According to the language specification (8.8.4) "The iteration variable corresponds to a read-only local variable with a scope that extends over the embedded statement."

Comment: public class MyClass
   {
       public int val;
   }
    class MyApp
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            IList<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();

            MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
            obj1.val = 10;
            list.Add(obj1);

            MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();
            obj2.val = 10;
            list.Add(obj2);

            foreach (MyClass obj in list)
            {
                obj.val = 20;
            }
        }
    }
refer this code. This works ;)

Comment: @Amy: yes it does but you are not modifying obj itself, you're modifying what it points to. There's a difference. Try to set obj to null and you'll get the compile error.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's giving compilation error.But it's quite strange.

Comment: @Amy: Not really. A value type variable stores the actual value. A reference type variable stores a reference to an object. It is the variable and not the referenced object that is read only and thus you can change the object via the reference, but you cannot change the reference itself.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I'm just crazy and thought the question was phrased differently than it was.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @technophile then why doesn't it work on my struct, but the bug is fixed when I change it to a class? See Deepfreezed's answer below.

Comment: I was incorrect about it working for structs; the compiler won't let you modify the iteration variable (including any of its fields) in that case.

Comment: but you can change/set its properties' values.

Comment: @toto' that is what the answer says, so I am not sure I understand your point. The point is, that you cannot change the _iteration variable_. For a reference type, that means that you cannot make it point to a different object or even null it, but you can change the properties of whatever it points to, as that doesn't change the variable itself. For value types, the variable holds the actual value (even for a complex struct) and thus you cannot change any part of this.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen ok maybe it was a redundant comment.

Answer (score 22):

You've asked 2 different questions here, lets take them in order.

### Does a foreach loop iterate by reference?

If you mean in the same sense as a C++ for loop by reference, then no.  C# does not have local variable references in the same sense as C++ and hence doesn't support this type of iteration.

### Will the change be persisted

Assuming that MyClass is a reference type, the answer is yes.  A class is a reference type in .Net and hence the iteration variable is a reference to the one variable, not a copy.  This would not be true for a value type.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, until you change the generic type from List to IEnumerable..

Comment: Someone care to elaborate on this?

Comment: I would live a further explanation of why this is the case

Comment: I think it might have something to do with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064426/1054322

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService is likely correct as to the example case this is referencing, where the IEnumerable acts on newly constructed objects. To my knowledge, there's no difference using IEnumerable vs. List.

Comment: This is plain false and misleading

Answer (score 16):

Well, it happened to me that my changes were not updated in a foreach loop when I iterated through var collection:

```
var players = this.GetAllPlayers();
foreach (Player player in players)
{
    player.Position = 1;
}
```

When I changed var to List it started working.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if the collection is cloned in such case.

Comment: When using foreach... there are 2 cases. 1. It could cast to IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T> if your class implements it.  If your collection is a struct it will be boxed. 2. Using GetEnumerator() method directly. It's a method pattern of sorts. It allows for basic enumerators on value types without expensive boxing. IEnumerable is not required at all. But then, no linq of course (we need traits or some sort of value type interfaces).

Answer (score 12):

You can in this instance (using a `List<T>`) but if you were to be iterating over the generic `IEnumerable<T>` then it becomes dependant on its implementation.

If it was still a `List<T>` or `T[]` for instance, all would work as expected.
The big gotcha comes when you are working with an `IEnumerable<T>` that was constructed using yield. In this case, you can no longer modify properties of `T` within an iteration and expect them to be present if you iterate the same `IEnumerable<T>` again.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it's interesting for you to lean that by version C# 7.3 it's possible to change values by reference provided that the enumerator's *Current* property returns a reference Type. The following would be valid (verbatim copy from the MS docs):

```
Span<int> storage = stackalloc int[10];
int num = 0;
foreach (ref int item in storage)
{
    item = num++;
}
```

Read more about this new feature at
[C# foreach statement | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

Answer (score 3):

this is true as long as it is not a struct.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know! Reading the top answers I was wondering why my code didn't work, but this explains it. Changed the struct to a class and \* *magic* \* it works.

Answer (score 2):

Well, without understanding exactly what you mean by "Iterate by reference", I can't answer specifically yes or no, but I can say that what's going on under the surface is that the .net framework is constructing an "enumerator" class for each time client code calls a foreach, for the life of the foreach, that maintains a reference pointer into the collection being iterated over, and each time your foreach iterates, ir "delivers" one item and "increments" the pointer or reference in the enumerator to the next item...

This happens regardless of whether the items in the collection you are iterating over are values types or reference types.

Answer (score 0):

obj is a reference to an item inside the List, hence if you change it's value it will persist. **Now what you should be concerned about is whether or not get_the_list(); is making a deep copy of the List or returning the same instance.**

Comment: It won't make a difference to the functionality he's interested in. Four copies of the same list will all reference the same actual objects, so whether you modify them from List1 or List3, either will result in the original object being modified. The only thing it will affect is if you add or remove items to/from the list, that wouldn't affect any copies of the list.

Comment: yes, the short answer of course is "yes, its a ref type", but the problems he might run into is if he it creates a copy of some original list, so if he calls get_the_list(); changes it and then calls get_the_list(); again somewhere else in the code, he might not get the results he expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's also why you cannot alter the enumerable object in the context of the foreach statement.