# Foreach struct weird compile error in C#

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, struct, foreach

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public string MyString;
        public int MyInt;
        public bool MyBool;
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        private List<MyStruct> MyPrivateVariable;

        public List<MyStruct> MyVariable
        {
            get
            {
                if (MyPrivateVariable == null)
                {
                    MyPrivateVariable = new List<MyStruct>();

                    MyPrivateVariable.Add(new MyStruct());
                    MyPrivateVariable.Add(new MyStruct());
                }

                return MyPrivateVariable;
            }
        }

        public void MyLoop()
        {
            foreach (MyStruct ms in MyVariable)
            {
                // Doesn't compile, but it works if you execute it through the Immediate window, or in Quickwatch
                ms.MyBool = false;

                // Compiles, works
                MyFunction(ms);
            }
        }

        public void MyFunction(MyStruct ms)
        {
            ms.MyBool = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any reasonable explanations for this?

The compiler returns:

> Error:
>       Cannot modify members of 'ms' because it is 'foreach iteration
>   variable'

**EDIT:**

Extra question:

I just tried changing a string from `MyFunction`, and it doesn't actually update `ms`. BUT: If I go to quickwatch and assign the same value there, it does update `ms`. Why does this happen if it shouldn't even be compiling in the first place, shouldn't quickwatch throw an exception?

**EDIT2:**

Ok, quick watch also works on a copy of `ms`, so that's why I can edit it's value, it doesn't actually alter the contents of `MyPrivateVariable`.

Comment: What's the compiler message say?

Comment: what's the compiler error message?

Comment: What do you mean by "it works in Immediate"? It will execute, but if your goal is to update the elements in `MyVariable`, then it does not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using them as mutable structs. Avoid doing that:

[Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Answer (score 6):

Struct has value type semantics. So any modification you make to the struct instance wouldn't affect the original instance. The C# compiler is trying to warn you of this.

Answer (score 5):

C# doesn't iterate structs by reference in the "foreach (MyStruct ms...)" so ms in that context is immutable.

Replace MyStruct with a class instead.

QuickWatch can manipulate value types on the stack.

Comment: Sometimes it can be useful to wrap a mutable struct in a simple exposed-field `Holder<T>` class for use in certain situations, but simply replacing a mutable struct with a mutable class to facilitate mutation of things in collections is a bad idea.  In general, each mutable object should have exactly one other object which encapsulates its mutable state.  If one wants to copy something from one `List<Holder<MyStruct>>` to an existing spot in another, `List2[1].Value = List1[3].Value;`.  To append one list item to another list, say `List2.Add(new Holder<MyStruct>(List1[3]))`.

Answer (score 1):

this is because struct is valuetype and not a reference type. if MyStruct was a class it would have compiled without issues. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612584/update-struct-in-foreach-loop-in-c) thread for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change what an iteration variable references: that is, you can't point the variable to a different instance (to find out why that is, see [Why is The Iteration Variable in a C# foreach statement read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776430/why-is-the-iteration-variable-in-a-c-foreach-statement-read-only)).

'Modifying' a struct (a value type) creates *a new instance* of the type, so the statement `ms.MyBool = false` is meaningless.

The call to `MyFunction(ms)` compiles because it operates on *a copy* of `ms` (though it still won't do what you might expect).

Comment: then why can I do modify them in Quick Watch? Nevermind, that also works on a copy of the struct, ugh why do structs even exist?

Comment: @Nico: Structs have a purpose, but *mutable* structs almost never do.

Comment: @Nico: All you're doing is modifying a copy that then gets thrown away. It's essentially a no-op.