# Modifying collection inside foreach loop using IEnumerable Where()

Tags: c#

Although the iterator variable in a `foreach` loop is immutable, I am able to modify my collection in the example below if I use `Where()` to do the modification:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        foreach (var listElement in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listElement + " ");
            list = list.Where(x => x != listElement).ToList();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + list.Count);
    }
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
Count: 0
```

Could someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: what was the expected output?

Comment: I expected this to have thrown an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in the `foreach (var listElement in list)` you are getting the enumerator for the reference of `list` at that point in time.

In your loop you assign a new instance to the `list` variable, but the enumerator the loop is using keeps the reference to the original enumerator.

What you can not do is mutate the original instance. i.e. perform `list.Remove(listElement)` as this would be mutating the actual data you are trying to enumerate

It might help if the code is expanded to what the foreach loop is actually doing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var listElement = enumerator.Current;
        Console.WriteLine(listElement + " ");
        list = list.Where(x => x != listElement).ToList();
    }
    enumerator.Dispose();

    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + list.Count);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Code shown never "modifies collection" in common meaning of that phrase (add/remove elements from existing collection), instead it creates new collection. As result there is no "collection modified" exceptions that you probably expect.

Answer (score 0):

In fact collection is not being modified as you are not adding/removing any item from the collection. In terms of reference to `list` variable, I do agree with Lee i.e. the loop is keeping the reference to the original enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

Because foreach uses an enumerator, and enumerators can't change the underlying collection, **but can, however, change any objects referenced by an object in the collection**. Refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650705/in-c-why-cant-i-modify-the-member-of-a-value-type-instance-in-a-foreach-loop). Also an interesting [article](http://www.lovethedot.net/2009/03/interesting-side-effect-of-concurrency.html) worth reading to understand the behavior