# what is the pattern for modifying a collection in C#

Tags: c#, iterator, collections, design-patterns, enumerator

What is the pattern (best practice) for such problem -- modifying elements (values) in collection?

Conditions:

- size of the collection is not changed (no element is deleted or added)
- modification is in-place

In C++ it was easy and nice, I just iterated trough a collection and changed the elements. But in C# iterating (using enumerator) is read-only operation (speaking in terms of C++, only const_iterator is available).

So, how to do this in C#?

Example: having sequence of "1,2,3,4" modification is changing it to "1, 2, 8, 9" but not "1, 2, 3" or "1, 2, 3, 4, 5".

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538301

Answer (score 5):

Typically you'd go by index instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
{
    if (ShouldChange(foo[i]))
    {
        foo[i] = GetNewValue(i);
    }
}
```

A more functional alternative is to create a method which returns a *new* collection which contains the desired "modified" data - it all depends on what you want to do though.

Comment: So it seems here C++ is more flexible, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that depends. The readonly part applies to the iterator itself. If you're iterating a collection of objects, you can change the state of the objects via the reference.

For a collection of value types, you cannot change the elements during iteration, but in that case you can run through the elements using a regular loop and an indexer.

Comment: Thank you. The first sentence is only partially true -- you don't know in advance if the element is immutable or not. In case of class the collection of it, is a collection of references -- this way you have to change the reference. And enumerator does not let you do this.

Comment: @macias: The iteration variable is always read-only. However, if it is a reference, you can modify the instance it points to, but you cannot change the reference itself. Please see the link in my comment for your question.

Comment: I fully understand that -- my question is was how to it (the loop) look better. In C++ it is really nice, so it is surprising that in C# it looks ugly. That's all.