# C# foreach on IEnumerable vs. List - element modification persistent only for array - Why?

Tags: c#, foreach, reference, ienumerable

In C#, I have noticed that if I am running a foreach loop on a LINQ generated `IEnumerable<T>` collection and try to modify the contents of each T element, my modifications *are not* persistent.

On the other hand, if I apply the `ToArray()` or `ToList()` method when creating my collection, modification of the individual elements in the foreach loop *are* persistent.

I suspect that this is in some way related to deferred execution, but exactly how is not entirely obvious to me. I would really appreciate an explanation to this difference in behavior.

Here is some example code - I have a class `MyClass` with a constructor and auto-implemented property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int val) { Str = val.ToString(); }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}
```

In my example application I use LINQ `Select()` to create two collections of `MyClass` objects based on a collection of integers, one `IEnumerable<MyClass>`, and one `IList<MyClass>` by applying the `ToList()` method in the end.

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var myClassEnumerable = ints.Select(i => new MyClass(i));
var myClassArray = ints.Select(i => new MyClass(i)).ToList();
```

Next, I run a foreach loop over each of the collections, and modify the contents of the looped-over `MyClass` objects:

```
foreach (var obj in myClassEnumerable) obj.Str = "Something";
foreach (var obj in myClassArray) obj.Str = "Something else";
```

Finally, I output the `Str` member  of the first element in each collection:

```
Console.WriteLine(myClassEnumerable.First().Str);
Console.WriteLine(myClassArray.First().Str);
```

Somewhat counter-intuitively, the output is:

```
1
Something else
```

Comment: edited the post for consistency. FWIW, the same would be true when using `MyClass[] arr = enumerable.ToArray()`. Now for real fun, try the same with `struct MyStruct { ... }` instead :)

Comment: Thanks, sehe. Yes, I kind of guessed that struct would not be an option anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deferred execution is the indeed the key point.

Executing `myClassEnumerable.First().Str` will reexecute your query `ints.Select(i => new MyClass(i));` and so it will give you a new IEnumerable with a new list of integers.

You can see this in action using your debugger. Put a breakpoint at the `new MyClass(i)` part of the IEnumerable select and you will see that this part get's hit again when you execute it for Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 3):

You are right, it is deferred execution.  A new MyClass instance is created each time you iterate the IEnumerable.  By calling ToList or ToArray you then create a List or Array and populate it with the new MyClass instances created from the iteration of the IEnumerable.