# How to replace "http:" with "https:" in a string with C#?

Tags: c#

I've stored all URLs in my application with "http://" - I now need to go through and replace all of them with "https:".  Right now I have:

```
    foreach (var link in links)
        {
            if (link.Contains("http:"))
            {
                /// do something, slice or replace or what?
            }
        }
```

I'm just not sure what the best way to update the string would be.  How can this be done?

Comment: google is your friend: Try `C# Replace string`.

Comment: holy downvotes... I tried googling!

Comment: I did not downvote anything, just to be clear.

Comment: I did. Sorry dude, but a very quick and simple google search shows a gazillion results, including all the examples you could ever need, this is not an obscure subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is your strings are in a collection, and since strings are immutable you can't change them directly.  Since you didn't specify the *type* of `links` (`List`? `Array`?) the right answer will change slightly. The easiest way is to create a new list:

```
links = links.Select(link => link.Replace("http://","https://")).ToList();
```

However if you want to minimize the number of changes and can access the string by index you can just loop through the collection:

```
for(int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++ )
{
    links[i] = links[i].Replace("http://","https://");
}
```

Comment: best answer because of linq

Comment: @DStanley I really wanted to say that this answer is best (no sacrasm at all), sorry if you felt offended

Answer (score 15):

If you're dealing with uris, you probably want to use [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.UriBuilder.aspx) since doing a string replace on structured data like URIs is not a good idea.

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(link);
builder.Scheme = "https";
Uri modified = builder.Uri;
```

It's not clear what the type of `links` is, but you can create a new collection with the modified uris using linq:

```
IEnumerable<string> updated = links.Select(link => {
    var builder = new UriBuilder(link);
    builder.Scheme = "https";
    return builder.ToString();
});
```

Comment: You beat me -- I was going to say the same thing. The question is really asking how to change the scheme of a URL, and while a string replacement is probably safe, this is the better way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: You can also use an object initializer to create the `UriBuilder` as an expression instead of as statements.  That would let you, for example, use a query expression: `var updated = from link in links select new UriBuilder(link) { Scheme = "https" }.ToString();`

Comment: @ranieuwe ist very correct. Easiest solution: Set  `builder.Port=-1`  after (!) changing the scheme to https. This will remove the port 80 information and the default https port will be used.

Answer (score 1):

based on your current code, `link` will not be replace to anything you want because it is read only (see here: [Why can't I modify the loop variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551696/why-cant-i-modify-the-loop-variable-in-a-foreach)). instead use `for`

```
for(int a = 0; a < links.Length; a++ )
{
    links[a] = links[a].Replace("http:/","https:/")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://myserver.xom/login.aspx?returnurl=**http**%3a%2f%2fmyserver.xom%2fmyaccount.aspx&q1=a%20b%20c&q2=c%2b%2b

What about the urls having also url in the querystring part? I think we should also replace them. And because of the url encoding-escaping this is the hard part of the job.

```
private void BlaBla()
{
    // call the replacing function
    Uri myNewUrl = ConvertHttpToHttps(myOriginalUrl);
}

private Uri ConvertHttpToHttps(Uri originalUri)
{
    Uri result = null;
    int httpsPort = 443;// if needed assign your own value or implement it as parametric 

    string resultQuery = string.Empty;
    NameValueCollection urlParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(originalUri.Query);

    if (urlParameters != null && urlParameters.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in urlParameters)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append("&");

            string value = urlParameters[key].Replace("http://", "https://");
            string valuEscaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(value);// this is important
            sb.Append(string.Concat(key, "=", valuEscaped));
        }
        resultQuery = sb.ToString();
    }

    UriBuilder resultBuilder = new UriBuilder("https", originalUri.Host, httpsPort, originalUri.AbsolutePath);
    resultBuilder.Query = resultQuery;

    result = resultBuilder.Uri;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) and some LINQ:

```
var httpsLinks = links.Select(l=>l.Replace("http://", "https://");
```

Comment: `link` is an element of a collection; the collection won't see the change.