# foreach iteration variable Error is giving

Tags: c#

```
foreach(string file in strAllFiles)
{
    foreach(char c in file)
    {
        if (c > 127)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("sp_ReplaceNonAsciiCharset", con);
                sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter sqlparam = new SqlParameter();
                sqlparam.ParameterName = "@non_ascii_char";
                sqlparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                sqlparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NChar;
                sqlparam.Size = 2;
                sqlparam.Value = c;
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add(sqlparam);
                object o = sqlcom.ExecuteScalar();
                int i = file.IndexOf(c);
                file1 = file.Remove(i, 1);
                file2 = file1.Insert(i, o.ToString());
                file = file2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the last line `file=file2`, I am getting the error:

> cannot assign to file because it is a foreach iteration variable

Comment: Please clearly specify what you intend to do! We cant help to solve it if you dont specify what you want to do!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551696/why-cant-i-modify-the-loop-variable-in-a-foreach

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.. you're trying to assign a value to the variable that is part of the `foreach` iteration..

Comment: Copy error message to google - almost only give answers...

Comment: You've listed a bunch of facts. Did you want to ask a question?

Comment: Funny how this downvoted-below-zero' question is the google featured response for the actual error message (google query: Cannot pass  as a ref or out argument because it is a 'foreach iteration variable')

Answer (score 3):

Its because you are changing the loop variable which is not allowed. One option is to add file1 to a separate list or **if you use "for" loop instead of foreach you can modify it.**

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're trying to modify strAllFiles collection you probably should use
   for instead of foreach:
2. Don't try to modify file in 
   foreach(char c in file)

Something like

```
for(int i=0; i < strAllFiles.Count; i++) 
{     
    var file = strAllFiles[i];    
    var newFileValue = file;    
    foreach(char c in file) 
    {
      if (c > 127)
      {
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
         {

           ...
           // modify newFileValue
           newFileValue = file2;

         } 
      }
    }
    // Modify collection
    strAllFiles[i] = newFileValue; 
}
```

Comment: here strAllfiles is an string array and it contains 6 files. how can I use i<strAllfiles.Count here ?

Comment: it was invisible from the code you put what type is strAllFiles. Just replace Count to Length.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
file = file2;
```

needs to be changed. As you cannot assign value to the variable that you are looping on in foreach. Perhaps, assign it to some new variable. The iteration variable is read-only and cannot be altered. From [Section 8.4.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of c# language specification.

> The iteration variable corresponds to a read-only local variable with a scope that extends over the embedded statement. During execution of a foreach statement, the iteration variable represents the collection element for which an iteration is currently being performed. A compile-time error occurs if the embedded statement attempts to modify the iteration variable (by assignment or the ++ and -- operators) or pass the iteration variable as a ref or out parameter.