# Why is foreach loop Read-Only in C#

Tags: c#, loops

Why is foreach loop a read only? I mean you can fetch the data but can't increase++ or decrease--. Any reason behind it? 
Yes I am a beginner :)

Exmaple:

```
int[] myArray={1,2,3};
foreach (int num in myArray)
{
  num+=1;
}
```

Comment: I think he's talking about the iteration variable, as in foreach ( Item theItem in theItemList )... theItem cannot be assigned to.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776430/why-is-the-iteration-variable-in-a-c-foreach-statement-read-only

Comment: Yes I am saying about foreach loop. Naturally it's a loop right? In for loop we can iterate through an array and change the value in the array same time but foreach doesn't work.

Comment: @Zai: well, not true strictly speaking; see my answer below.

Comment: What I think is even more interesting is that you also can't add or remove from the collection from within the `foreach`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because foreach is meant to iterate over a container, making sure each item is visited exactly once, without changing the container, to avoid nasty side effects.

See: [foreach in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(VS.80).aspx)

If you meant why would changes to an element like an integer not affect a container of integers, well this is because the variable of iteration in this case would be a value type and is copied, e.g.:

```
// Warning: Does not compile
foreach (int i in ints)
{
  ++i; // Would not change the int in ints
}
```

Even if the variable of iteration was a reference type, whose operations returned a new object, you wouldn't be changing the original collection, you would just be reassigning to this variable most of the time:

```
// Warning: Does not compile
foreach (MyClass ob in objs)
{
  ob=ob+ob; // Reassigning to local ob, not changing the one from the original 
            // collection of objs
}
```

The following example has the potential to actually modify the object in the original collection by calling a *mutating* method:

```
// Warning: Does not compile
foreach (MyClass ob in objs)
{
  ob.ChangeMe(); // This could modify the object in the original collection
}
```

To avoid confusion with regard to value vs reference types and the scenarios mentioned above (along with some reasons related to optimization), MS chose to make the variable of iteration `readonly`.

Comment: When you say `// This could modify the object in the original collection`, that would be only if the collection was not a pure IEnumerable, ie a Collection or a List, right?

Answer (score 9):

Because the current element is returned by value(i.e. copied). And modifying the copy is useless. If it is a reference type you can modify the content of that object, but can't replace the reference.

Perhaps you should read the documentation of `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`. That should make it clearer. The most important bit is that `IEnumerable<T>` has a property `Current` of type `T`. And this property has only a getter, but no setter.

But what would happen if it had a setter?

- It would work well with arrays and Lists
- It wouldn't work well with complex containers like hashtables, ordered list because the change causes larger changes in the container(for example a reordering), and thus invalidates the iterator. (Most collections invalidate the iterators if they get modified to avoid inconsistent state in the iterators.)
- In LINQ it does make no sense at all. For example with `select(x=>f(x))` the values are results of a function and have no permanent storage associated.
- With iterators written with the `yield return` syntax it doesn't make sense either

Comment: "And modifying the copy is useless." What if I want to do something like sum the square of all the numbers in a list? It can be done with the read-only restriction, but it's often useful to modify a copy.

Comment: +1 for "The most important bit is that IEnumerable<T> has a property Current of type T. And this property has only a getter, but no setter." Finally an answer that explains it thoroughly.

Comment: But if you can update a property on the object that is referred to by the iteration variable, couldn't this also change the ordering in an ordered list?

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is designed to visit each item in a collection exactly once, and does not use an explicit "loop index"; if you want more control over the loop and have a loop index, use `for`.

EDIT: You can change the items in the collection being iterated on inside a `foreach` loop. For example:

```
foreach(Chair ch in mychairs)
{
    ch.PaintColour = Colour.Green; //this alters the chair object *in* the collection.
}
```

You cannot, however, add or remove items to/from the collection.

Comment: Actually, you cannot modify a field/property of the object refered to by the variable of iteration, either.

Comment: @Michael: The code I posted works OK for me. I am using .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn only the iteration variable is read only, not the object is refers to.