# C# Edit a variable of arraylist index

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, arraylist

I got an arraylist of rectangles and I want to edit the X & Y values of all of them.

I tried using a foreach loop

```
        foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangles)
            rect.X += 1;
```

But this wouldn't work as it's read-only, so I tried a regular for loop

```
        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.Count; i++)
            rectangles[i].X += 1;
```

And for some reason this wouldn't work either, because rectangles[i] just doesn't have any of rectangle's methods.

Then I stumbled across a post somewhere on stackoverflow about how to call methods of elements of an arraylist. And I haven't been able to find examples of this, so I hope someone can clear this up.

```
(Unit.unitArray[selectedUnit] as MyClass).DisplayUnitAttributes()
```

But I have no idea how to put this to use, I don't understand what Unit is supposed to be replaced with, and I'm guessing MyClass would be Rectangle...

Any help is appreciated!

TLDR: I want to iterate over an arraylist with rectangles, and edit the X & Y values of them.

Comment: Could you sum up the differences for me? I'm used to Java where ArrayList is an interface of List.

Comment: @GrantWinney Tried for (int i = 0; i < rectangles2.Count; i++)
                rectangles2[i].X += 1; where rectangles2 is a List<Rectangle>, doesn't work because "Return value is not a variable"...

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That doesn't work, and I don't know what a struct is.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Btw, I'm using C#'s Rectangle class, I just want a way to edit values of it in an arraylist, I'm getting linked everywhere, it's not helping me. Can you please just answer my question.

Comment: I like how everyone is deleting their answers and comments, please only post if you actually know what you're doing.

Comment: I know what am i doing. i just want to clear up everything. i dont like extra noise! :)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You literally deleted your own comment. You wouldn't do that unless you knew it was redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you have got. `"Return value is not a variable"`

Rectangle is not a class. its an struct which is not reference type so you have to assign new value into it.

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

// rectangles.Add(x); make your list here

for (int index = 0; index < rectangles.Count; index++)
{
    Rectangle r = rectangles[index];
    r.x += 1;
    rectangles[index] = r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's act like this because ArrayList is not typed. It's better to use a `List<T>` instead (where T is your class, in your example it will be a Rectangle). Here is [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can't modify object this way in the foreach loop. More info on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004755/why-is-foreach-loop-read-only-in-c-sharp).

About this example: `(Unit.unitArray[selectedUnit] as MyClass).DisplayUnitAttributes()`
It's called casting. You can read more about this on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr). So in your code it should looks like this: `(rectangles[i] as Rectangle).X += 1;`. You also should check if result of this casting is not null etc. But better read previous link to understand this.

Comment: I know what casting is, and I tried ---- for (int i = 0; i < rectangles2.Count; i++)
                (rectangles[i] as Rectangle).X += 1; ---- but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, okey, your Rectangle is a struct, not a class. Sorry! Second answer is good then ;)