# Getting Enumeration Exception while removnig element from collection list using foreach

Tags: javascript, java, c#, selenium-webdriver

when i tried to remove element from the list collection using foreach im getting enumeration exception .i searched in net but im not getting proper explanation for the problem . if anyone knows about  this share the information

Comment: Is this java, javascript, or C#? Please edit your tags to only include the relevant languages. Please also read [ask], and include a [mcve]

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004755/why-is-foreach-loop-read-only-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

You can't remove an item from the same ICollection which foreach is currently running on. If you want to remove items from same collection while inside a loop, use a secondary list

```
//Define a secondary variable
var items = new List<string>{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
var secondaryList = new List<string>(items);

//Now iterate and remove according you want from second variable
foreach(var i in items)
{
  if(i=="Two") { secondaryList.remove(i) }
}

//Once iteration is over, copy back
items = new List<string>(secondaryList);
```

Comment: secondaryList references the same collection! how does this really work?

Comment: Secondary list should not be a reference to previous variable. It should be a different variable with copied contents only.

Comment: If it helps you, can you mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: This will not work, you might have wanted to do var secondaryList = new List<string>(items); and in the last step items = new List<string>(secondaryList).

Comment: Exactly, I've modified the code for any future people to refer. Thanks @AlexandruClonțea

Answer (score -1):

Yes, previous posters are correct. One should not remove items from a collection one is iterating over. It may invalidate the iterator. First determine which items you need to remove, then iterate over that list to remove the items from the original collection. Something like this:

```
IList<int> myCollection = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
IList<int> itemsToRemove = new List<int>();

foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    if (item % 2 == 0)
    {
        itemsToRemove.Add(item);
    }
}

foreach(var toRemove in itemsToRemove)
{
    myCollection.Remove(item);
}
```