# How to change each element of a List<long>?

Tags: c#

I have a List of different DayTime (Ticks). I try to get a list of the time remaining from now to each time element.

```
List<long> diffliste = new List<long>(m_DummyAtTime);

// 864000000000 ≙ 24h
diffliste.ForEach(item => { item -= now; if (item < 0) item += 864000000000; }); 

// test, does also not work
// diffliste.ForEach(item => { item -= 500; });
```

However, the list is not changed. Do I miss something?
(`now` is `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var times = diffliste.Select(ticks => new DateTime(ticks) - DateTime.Now);
```

Will return a collection of TimeSpans between now and each time.

Without using Linq:

```
List<TimeSpan> spans = diffliste.ConvertAll(ticks => new DateTime(ticks) - DateTime.Now);
```

(modified as suggested by Marc)

Comment: This **does not** update the existing list, which is what the OP is asking for. It also **does not** return a collection (it returns a deferred *sequence*)

Comment: @Marc, I know but I suspected that was what the OP needed though he did not explicitly request it

Comment: This looks like a nice solution. Does it require LINQ or a special .NET-Framework? For compatibility reasons, I couldn't use it then.

Comment: @Nikodemus, yes it uses Linq to objects, I guess you can ignore my post if you don't have access to .net >= 3.5

Comment: @Nikodemus, I've updated my post with a solution that does not use linq

Comment: Your updated answer would be cleaner and more efficient as: `List<TimeSpan> spans = diffliste.ConvertAll(ticks => ...);`

Comment: Ah, ok. That's what I was hoping for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing a standalone copy in a local variable (well, parameter actually), not the actual value in the list. To do that, perhaps:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < diffliste.Count ; i++) {
    long val = diffliste[i]; // copy the value out from the list
    ... change it
    diffliste[i] = val; // update the value in the list
}
```

Ultimately, your current code is semantically similar to:

```
long firstVal = diffliste[0];
firstVal = 42;
```

which *also* does not change the first value in the list to 42 (it only changes the local variable).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of an item inside a foreach cycle.
You can do it using a classic for cycle or creating and assigning items to a new list.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < diffliste.Count; i++) 
{
    long value = diffliste[i];
    // Do here what you need
    diffliste[i] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iteration var in a foreach cycle is immutable, so you cannot change it. You either have to create a new list or use a for cycle... see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776430/why-is-the-iteration-variable-in-a-c-sharp-foreach-statement-read-only).

Comment: The OP is not using `foreach`, they are using `ForEach` - while similar, this exposes the value as a parameter to a delegate, which *is* mutable... it just doesn't change the underlying value in the list in any way