# C# how swap object to object of inherite class with only their reference - It is posible?

Tags: c#, pointers, reference

**EDIT: In considerations i didn't have access to list**

**EDIT: I changed example to more advanced**

**EDIT: Fixed example ;P**

**EDIT: Again edited**
I'm sure that i got vote down cause you guys didn't understand orgin of my considerations. I know it is posible with pointers in C++ but not sure it is still posible in C#. And i didnt ask cuase i don't know how to change element in List! I just want to make it without access to that LIST! This is only example cuase real live example is to complicated to introduce here...

I Wonder if it's posible to do something like this
        class Foo
        {
            public int foo = 100;
            EventHandler something;

```
        public Foo()
        {
            something += smth;
        }

        public void doSmth()
        {
            something(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public static void smth(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sender = new Foo();
        }
    }

    class Boo : Foo
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> something;

        public Boo()
        {
            foo = 1;
            something += smth;
        }           

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

        Foo foo = new Boo();
        list.Add(foo);

        foreach (Foo f in list)
            f.doSmth();

        foreach (Foo f in list)
            Console.WriteLine(f.foo);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

My output is 1 but i want to get 100. It is posible to change object from list by its reference ?

Comment: I don't understand why i get downvote now, when i just edited my example and it isn't trivial problem. Maybe it is impossible to do this in that way, but you can comment when you vote down

Comment: I'm not sure either. Its not exactly a model question, but -5 seems a little harsh.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't have access to the list at all. If you only have access to an object you know is in a list, but no reference to the actual list it is impossible to insert something into the list. Here's another question which might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776430/why-is-the-iteration-variable-in-a-c-sharp-foreach-statement-read-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you didn't get the reference you thought:

```
Foo boo = list[0];
boo = new Boo;
```

This makes a *new* reference (called boo) and assigns the reference in `list[0]` to it. You then assign a `Boo` object to that *new, local* reference. When you iterate over the `List`, the reference stored *there* hasn't been changed at all, so you see the behavior.

Instead, just write:

```
list[0] = new Boo();
```

**Note** I actually wasn't sure that would work, so I tested it, and it does! Because the code is kind of odd, I would reccommend finding a different way to mutate it (like removing the old object and adding a new one) in order to improve readability/maintainability.

```
        List<FancyText> test = new List<FancyText>();
        test.Add(new FancyText { Text = "test" });
        test[0] = new FancyText() { Text = "final" };
```

The collection holds the object with "final" in it.

**Update** To your edit, you can *almost* do that:

```
private delegate void refHandler (ref Award sender);
private event refHandler test;
```

However, you can't pass `this` as a `ref` parameter, as it is read-only (makes sense, right? you can't assign yourself to something else, that would be weird).

Comment: Yeah i know, but for in considerations i didn't have access to list

Comment: @KarolChudzik If it was a function parameter, then you could use `ref` as Selman suggested. Thats about the best you can do though.

Comment: Yhym but this will not be a function parameter

Comment: @KarolChudzik Then you are pretty much stuck. Perhaps providing something closer to the actual code will help us help you.

Comment: Please look for new more advance example

Comment: @KarolChudzik That example doesn't really make any sense. You raise an event, that isn't listened to by anything, and something is supposed to mutate?

Comment: @KarolChudzik See my update. You can get awfully close with the event.

Comment: Sorry again forget about some code ;) i just add code to do something with event

Comment: so you also think this is imposible ?

Comment: @KarolChudzik As written, yes, its impossible. You'll have to make *some* change.

Comment: @Downvoter. Would love to hear why you feel my answer is not useful/of low quality. I'm always open to critique.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. When you assign a new reference `boo` is no longer referencing the old location, but `list[0]` still holds a reference there and changing `boo`'s reference doesn't affect it. Because there is no connection between them, you can think them as two different variables that holds a reference to the same location. Like this:

```
string foo = "foo";
string bar = foo;
bar = "bar";
```

Changing the reference of `bar` does not affect `foo`. That's the behaviour or reference types. Changing a variables reference would be only possible when you use `ref` modifier in function parameters.Have a look at this question for more info about that: [What is the use of “ref” for reference-type variables in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961717/what-is-the-use-of-ref-for-reference-type-variables-in-c)

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain if there is something wrong. or if you just downvoted without any reason let me know so I can stop thinking what might be wrong about my answer.

Comment: I thought you had a good answer. Not sure why people are downvoting answers here (except the other one for some reason). I've had 2 that were later removed.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with inheritance.  You simply never modified the list.  Look at this code:

```
Foo boo = list[0];
boo = new Boo();
```

After the first line, `boo` refers to the same in-memory object as the first element in `list`.  But after the *second* line, it refers to a *new* in-memory object.  *Not* the first element in the list.  Stop there in a debugger and examine both the object and the list, they're different.

Afterward you then go on to print the elements from the list.  You never print the value of `boo`, and never modify the list.  To update the element in the list, you need to set it:

```
list[0] = boo;
```

**Edit:** Your updated example doesn't even compile.  This code won't work:

```
foreach (Foo f in list)
    f.doSmth();
```

Because there is no method called `doSmth()` on `Foo`.  Are you trying to check if any given element in the collection is an instance of `Boo` and invoke the method if it is?  In that case you can check the type:

```
foreach (Foo f in list)
    if (f is Boo)
        (f as Boo).doSmth();
```

Though in *most* cases I'd argue that isn't really good design.  There are cases which call for it, sure.  But it's more likely that your `Foo` and `Boo` modeling are breaking an abstraction somewhere.  If the collection is of type `Foo` then any operation on that collection *should* only user operations on type `Foo`.

Comment: Yeah i know, but in considerations i didn't have access to list.

Comment: @KarolChudzik: That doesn't make sense.  If you "don't have access" to the array, how are you getting a value from it in the first place?  Perhaps your example doesn't actually demonstrate the problem?

Comment: This example doesn't demonstrate problem, i will edit post. But aware it will be strange example ;)

Comment: Please look for new more advance example

Comment: Fixed, please look :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a variable `boo` with a reference to the `Foo` object in the first spot in `list`, i.e., the first `new Foo()` you did.

```
Foo boo = list[0];
```

When you do the following you overwrite the variable `boo`'s reference to the `Foo` object with a reference to your newly constructed `Boo` object.

```
boo = new Boo;
```

To do what your manual test specifically is asking for, you could do the following

```
Foo boo = list[0] == new Boo();
```

This will update both the variable `boo` and the first spot in `list` with a new reference to your newly created Boo object. This will output:

```
1
100
```

Now, when this is said. It is technically possible to use references directly using the `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords. This will add several restrictions. Here is my best attempt at replicating your code using unsafe code:

```
//Requres project properties be set to Allow Unsafe Code
struct Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo[] list = new Foo[2];
    list[0] = new Foo { Bar = 100 };
    Foo foo = new Foo { Bar = 100 };
    list[1] = foo;

    fixed (Foo* boo = list)
        *boo = new Foo { Bar = 1 };

    foreach (Foo f in list)
        Console.WriteLine(f.Bar); //Prints 1 then 100

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This will also output:

```
1
100
```

However, it isn't really a general example. What happens if you want to point to an index other than 0 of the list. You'd have to swap out the `fixed` part with something like the following:

```
fixed (Foo* plist = list)
{
    const int offset = 1;
    Foo* boo = plist + offset;
    *boo = new Foo { Bar = 1 };
}
```

This would output:

```
100
1
```

What you lose is referencing class objects, only structs, this means no inheritance, and having to use the fixed keyword, and probably much more.