# c# foreach loop not able to add literals in an array

Tags: c#

Firstly I know that I can't use a foreach loop in C# to add values in let's say an array... But why? Why for example I can't do this

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
foreach (int item in numbers)
{
    numbers[item] = 2;
}
```

Does it have something to do with the actual realisation of the foreach loop in the back-end? And how does the foreach loop exactly work? I know that it goes through the whole collection(array) but how exactly?

Comment: What exactly do you expect this to do? It will fail because you try to access index 7 and 9 of an array that is only 6 long. *Array sizes are fixed in C#.*

Comment: you can't add items to an array regardless of the loop type you use.

Comment: @SelmanGenç of course i can ... `int[] numbers = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = 10;
            }`

Comment: @DavidG A little explaination please? I didn't quite get you

Comment: That isn't adding items, it's overwriting existing ones. You cannot add new items.

Comment: Be aware that unlike e.g. JavaScript's `foreach`, C#'s `foreach` enumerates *values*, not their *indices*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm confused lol... isn't a foreach loop same as a for loop but the difference is that the foreach loop with go through the whole collection(array) ?

Comment: @john A "regular" for loop gives you successive `int`s from index `0` to `Length - 1`. With a `foreach` loop, you don't know the index and only have the current value.

Comment: On your 5th iteration of the loop, `item` becomes the value 7 because that's the value of the item in the 5th position in your array. Then you try to access the 7th value in your array with `numbers[item]` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @john: Not quite. In C#, a `foreach` loop could be seen as the "same" as a `for` loop, where you automatically get the current item in a variable you specify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is The Iteration Variable in a C# foreach statement read-only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776430/why-is-the-iteration-variable-in-a-c-sharp-foreach-statement-read-only)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: This is not a duplicate. The other question is asking for a rationale why one cannot assign a value to the iteration variable in a `foreach` loop (which would then be propagated to the underlying collection). This question asks either why the indicated way of reading from the iteration variable does not work (which appears to be based upon the assumption that the iteration variable contains the index rather than the value), or why no items can be added to an array.

Comment: Why not just initialize the whole thing to 2 in the first place if that's what you want?

Comment: @EJoshuaS It's easy to imagine this being a simplified version of a more complex problem. This specific example might not be exactly what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you should try with `string[] numbers = { "one", "four", "three", "five", "seven", "nine", };` instead. You seem to be confused with `int[]` because the element type is the same type (`int`) as the type we use with the indexer. With a `string[]` that does not happen.

Comment: @EJoshuaS ... Well i was just wondering why isn't possible to use a foreach loop to assign some values at some positions just like a for loop... this was only an example

Comment: @1blustone I assume that that's what he was doing, but it's not clear from the post.

Comment: You can do `foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    numbers[2] = item;
}`, that will work. But what do you want?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen that will definitely not do what was requested. You're repeatedly setting the third element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm looking at this:

```
numbers[item] = 2;
```

In this expression, you're using the `item` variable like an **index**, as if it had the values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, etc. *That's not how the foreach iteration variable works for C#*. The only language I know that does it this way is Javascript.

Remember that `foreach` and `for` are not the same thing. Just about every other language, including C#, gives you the actual array values in the `item` variable of a `foreach` loop: `1`,`4`, `3`, `5` etc. Now, these are integers, so you *could* try to use them as indexes. You can run the loop for a while like that... until you get to the value `7`. At this point, your array only has six values. You're trying to do this:

```
numbers[7] = 2;
```

for an array where the largest valid index you can use is `5`.

This is true even taking your modification of the array into account. Let's look at the array after each iteration through the loop:

```
{ 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9 }  //initial state
{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9 }  // after 1st iteration (index 0). Value at index 0 is 1, so item as index 1 is set to 2
{ 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 9 }  // after 2nd iteration (index 1). Value at index 1 is now 2, so item at index 2 is set to 2
{ 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 9 }  // after 3rd iteration (index 2). Value at index 2 is now 2, so item at index 2 is set to 2
{ 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2 }  // after 4th iteration (index 3). Value at index 3 is 5, so item at index 5 is set to 2
// The 5th iteration (index 4). Value at index 4 is 7, which is beyond the end of the array
```

For the **why** of this... it sounds like you're used to a more dynamic language. Some these other languages, like php or Javascript, *don't have real arrays at all* in the pure computer science sense. Instead, they have **collection** types they'll *call* an array, but when you get down to it are really something different.

C# has *real* arrays, and real arrays have a *fixed* size. If what you really want is a *collection*, C# has collections, too. You can use `List<T>` objects, for example, to get an array-like collection you can append to easily.

For the other languages, the results vary depending on what you're talking about, but for the most permissive the result of your 5th iteration is something like this:

```
{ 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2,  ,2 }
```

Note the missing value at index 6. That kind of things leads to mistakes that slip through your tests and don't show up until run-time. You also need to start wondering just how densely or sparsely the array will be filled, because the best strategy for handling these arrays can vary wildly depending on your answer... everything from just a big backing array with empty nodes that the programmer has to know about all the way to Hashtables and Dictionaries. And, by the way, C# again has these options available to you.

Comment: ok but `{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9 }  // after 1st iteration. Index at 1st value (1) set to 2` why does it start from the index 1, why not index 0?

Comment: I was talking sequentially, rather than by index. The first value in the array is at position `0`, and has a value of `1`. So after the first iteration, the item at index position `1` is set to have a value of `2`. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: So that's why "You can't use an foreach loop for assigning values in an array" as it is said in msdn haha

Answer (score 4):

You are passing in the value of an item (*your variable, `item`, will be the value of the array at each position in sequence, not the index*) in the array as the index. The index used there is meant to be the **position** of the item you are attempting to access, not the value. So each iteration of the loop you are calling:

- `numbers[1]`
- `numbers[4]`
- `numbers[3]`
- `numbers[5]`
- `numbers[7]`
- `numbers[9]`

The array has 6 numbers, so when you get to `numbers[7]`, you are asking for a value that is not there, hence the exception.

A better method of doing what you are trying to do would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = 2;
}
```

On each iteration of this loop you would be accessing:

- `numbers[0]`
- `numbers[1]`
- `numbers[2]`
- `numbers[3]`
- `numbers[4]`
- `numbers[5]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to [step through your code in a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

A `for` statement is more like a `while` statement, not like a `foreach`.

The line `int[] numbers = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9 };` create this:

```
numbers[0] = 1;
numbers[1] = 4;
numbers[2] = 3;
numbers[3] = 5;
numbers[4] = 7;
numbers[5] = 9;
```

Your `foreach` statement does this:

```
numbers[1] = 2;
numbers[4] = 2;
numbers[3] = 2;
numbers[5] = 2;
numbers[7] = 2; <- this line overflows your array!
numbers[9] = 2; <- and so would this.
```

You have to learn the difference between an array index and an array value.

Comment: I know "the difference between an array index and an array value" lol... just don't know how the foreach loop exactly works in the implementation

Comment: @john It's been demonstrated multiple times. It's equivalent to a for loop, where you store the current value. `for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { int currentValue = array[i]; }`

Comment: The `numbers[9]` part isn't actually a problem since the value there is changed to `2` before the code runs. But the `7` still blows up.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create counter, in other case you trying to access item outside of array

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{ 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
int i = 0;
foreach (int item in numbers)
{
    numbers[i] = 2;
    i++;
}

// Print the items of the array
foreach (int item in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Yea this is my question... why am I accessing item outside the array? Does it have to do something with the implementation of the foreach loop?

Comment: @john: What concrete operation do you mean by "accessing item outside the array", where it is not clear to you that you are using an index outside of the range of valid indices for the array? Your array has a length of 6, hence your array indices must be between 0 and 5 (both inclusive) to be "within" the array.

Comment: well if i do this `int[] numbers = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
foreach (int item in numbers)
{
    numbers[item] = 2;
}` I get an IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @john: Have you checked the values that `item` assumes in each of your iterations? You will find that it will have the values `7` and `9` at some point, both of which are not within the bounds of valid indices for your array.

Comment: @john you are passing in the value of an item in the array as the index. So you are passing in numbers[1], numbers[4], numbers[3], numbers[5], numbers[7], numbers[9]. The collection has 6 numbers, so when you get to numbers[7], you are asking for a value that is not there...