# Release error with C#

Tags: c#

Why I get the error as collection was modified an enumeration opearation may not execute while releasing the application in C#?

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: Then read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: +1 the other comments and code always helps!

Comment: @user1511049 Moreover, consider to write a question, not a chat message! You have to read two or three times your questions before to submit! Please, consider an edit with more details!

Comment: This could be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/759985/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/759985/674700)

Answer (score 2):

it means you directly/indirectly tries to change one of references to objects in your collection.

in an iteration:

```
foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    item = new Item(); // Error
    item.Prop = "Something"; //OK
}
```