# Changing collection inside foreach

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code:

```
foreach (OrderItem item in OrderInfo.order)
{
     orderItemViews.Single(i => i.numericUpDown.Name == item.id.ToString()).numericUpDown.Value = item.count;
}
```

It gives an exception.
I know that I can't change the collection inside *foreach*
How can I change this code to make it work? Best of all if it would be LINQ code.

exception says that "The collection was modified". sorry can't provide real message of exception because it in non-english

sorry guys. I've found where collection is changing. It was inside *numericUpDown_ValueChanged* handler. anyway I've got an answer. thank you

Comment: when you changing your OrderInfo.order collection inside this loop? As i understood you just update your interface...

Comment: What's the exception?  What is the type of orderItemViews, and what members does it have?

Comment: Is this code runs outside UI thread?

Comment: May be you will write what type of exception you got?

Comment: I see that OrderInfo.order is not changing. But I get this exception anyway. I don't know why

Comment: In the code you have posted you are only making one assignment and that is not to the `OrderInfo.order` collection, we need to see more code.  Is this nested inside another loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to modify a list in a 'foreach' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759966/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-a-list-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ToList()`, Like this :

```
foreach (OrderItem item in OrderInfo.order.ToList())
{
     orderItemViews.Single(i => i.numericUpDown.Name == item.id.ToString()).numericUpDown.Value = item.count;
}
```

Or use normal for loop :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < OrderInfo.order.Count; i++)
{
     OrderItem item = OrderInfo.order[i];
     orderItemViews.Single(i => i.numericUpDown.Name == item.id.ToString()).numericUpDown.Value = item.count;
}
```

**Tip** : Performance wise, It's better to use the second way.

Comment: Are you sure can this helped? Where are you see `odrer` collection changes?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan possibly, it is a side-effect in the `Value` setter -- we can't know without seeing the code. However, this is the solution for the enumerator invalidation problem. The `for` loop will solve that problem for sure.

Comment: @acrilige you don't know that. He may be changing the collection the `Value` setter. You can't know without seeing the full code.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do, when I need to modify the collection.

```
foreach (OrderItem item in OrderInfo.order.ToList())
{
     ...
}
```

Create a copy. Enumerate the copy, but update the original one.

Comment: Are you sure can this helped? Where are you see `odrer` collection changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension ToEach static method:

```
public delegate void ToEachTransformAction<T>(ref T Telement);

[Extension()]
public static void ToEach<T>(Generic.IList<T> thislist, ToEachTransformAction<T> Transform)
    {
        for (var n = 0; n < thislist.Count; n++)
        {
            Transform.Invoke(thislist(n));
        }
    }
```