# Remove Column from Data Table C#

Tags: c#, database, excel, datatable

Im currently mapping fields from an uploaded excel document to a data table. I want the columns that are not selected to be removed but they still show.

Here is my code:

```
if(DT.Columns.IndexOf("First Name") != -1)
                DT.Columns["First Name"].ColumnName = "First NameMap";
            DT.Columns[mapping.FirstNameColumnId].ColumnName = "First Name";

            if (DT.Columns.IndexOf("Last Name") != -1)
                DT.Columns["Last Name"].ColumnName = "Last NameMap";
            DT.Columns[mapping.LastNameColumnId].ColumnName = "Last Name";

            if (DT.Columns.IndexOf("Email Address") != -1)
                DT.Columns["Email Address"].ColumnName = "Email AddressMap";
            DT.Columns[mapping.EmailColumnId].ColumnName = "Email Address";


            int ColumnCounter = 0;
            foreach(DataColumn column in DT.Columns)
            {
                if(ColumnCounter != mapping.FirstNameColumnId && ColumnCounter != mapping.LastNameColumnId && ColumnCounter != mapping.EmailColumnId)
                {
                    DT.Columns.Remove(column);
                }
            }
```

Comment: When you step through this code in the debugger, where specifically does it fail?  Is that `foreach` loop entered at all?  Is the `if` statement therein entered at all?  When you call `.Remove()` on the target column, is it removed from that object?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: The code isnt failing as such. It goes into the DT.Columns.Remove(column); but all the original columns from the excel sheet are still being displayed. I just want it to show the first name , last name, and email

Comment: You should beware of modifying the Columns collection within the foreach - to be safe make a copy with .ToList() - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413099/changing-collection-inside-foreach

Comment: where did you bind your datatable to "excel sheets"?

Comment: As PaulF said, you should not modify a collection within its own foreach loop. You can use a copy as he says, or use a For loop, but be careful the index will change when an item is removed from the collection. You could also just use a lambda expression to filter the columns to whatever columns you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   DataTable t;
   t.Columns.Remove("columnName");
   t.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```