# Taking an Object from one Collection to another

Tags: c#

is this a correct way to move objects from one list to another?

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeObject> toBeProcessed = 
                                new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>();


public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> ToBeProcessed 
{
    get
    {
        return toBeProcessed ;
    }
    set
    {
        //implements INotifyProperyChanged:
        SetField(ref toBeProcessed , value, "ToBeProcessed"); 
    }
}


public void MoveSelected(ObservableCollection<SomeOject> SelectedObjects)
{
    foreach (var obj in SelectedObjects)
    {
        ToBeProcessed.Add(obj);
        SelectedObjects.Remove(obj);
    }
}
```

is this the right way? if yes, is there a better way?

**Update**, sorry figured that it cant be done in a foreach loop so change it to this

```
for (int i = SelectedObjects.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ToBeProcessed.Add(SelectedObjects[i]);
    SelectedObjects.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

is it still the right way?

Comment: this code will throw an exception `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` at the foreach loop

Comment: i think it is better suited for CodeReview


Comment: Where are you calling `MoveSelected`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel its public so from the class that has SelectedObjects

Comment: Collections within foreach loops are immutable http://stackoverflow.com/a/759985/1226915

Comment: @Jehof what if i change to a for loop?

Comment: on a side note: there's something called a `ConcurrentDictionary` in c# that allows for such behavior, although in all fairness, this only works on multi-cpu systems.

Comment: Your update with for loop is broken. you need a reverse for

Comment: @SriramSakthivel and now its reversed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could simply do:

```
foreach (var obj in SelectedObjects)
    ToBeProcessed.Add(obj);

SelectedObjects.ClearItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a collection when you go through it no matter with index or foreach. However, from your description, **SelectedObjects** here behaves more like a "temporary collection", which is selected from another collection of **ToSelectObjects**, so you may not need to remove objects from it, but after adding them into **ToBeProcessed**, foreach loop **SelectedObjects** again and remove them from **ToSelectObjects**...