# List.forEach unable to modify element?

Tags: arrays, foreach, dart

I'm attempting to create a list of lists to imitate the functionality of a 2D array in Dart, and I was having trouble for a while figuring out how to make it work.

I originally used `List.forEach` in order to create the lists and fill them, but after each loop, it's as if I never created the lists. Here's what that code looked like:

```dart
currentMap = new List<List<int>>(height);
currentMap.forEach((e) {
    e = new List<int>(width);
    e.forEach((f) {
        f = 1;
    });
});
```

Printing `currentMap` resulted in a list of `null`. Here's what I have now:

```dart
currentMap = new List<List<int>>(height);
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    currentMap[i] = new List<int>(width);
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        currentMap[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

This works exactly as I expected it to.

I understand that this is probably a very basic issue, and I am assuming that `forEach` does not allow you to modify the element, but I wanted some confirmation on that, and the Dart API docs do not specify except with the phrase "apples the function f to each element..." which may just not be clear to me.

Also, I am aware of things like the `List.filled()` constructor -- this is just how I am starting to build towards other functionality.

EDIT: Okay, I think I understand now. Arguments are "pass-by-sharing" which means that a copy of a reference to the object is made. This means that you can modify a member of a mutable object that is pointed to by the argument (as follows):

```dart
void function(MyObject o) {
    o.x = 5;
}
```

but trying to change what `o` points to will not change the argument after exiting the function, such as this:

```dart
void function(MyObject o) {
    MyObject p = new MyObject();
    o = p;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dart does not have variable references, all elements are passed as a reference to an object, not to a variable. (In other words, Dart is purely "call-by-sharing" like both Java and JavaScript).

That means that the `e` parameter to the `forEach` callback is just a normal local variable, and assigning to it has no effect outside the callback. The same goes for iterators: they return the value in the iterable, but it has no reference back to the iterable after that.

The double loop is what you want when you do "read-modify-write". You read a value from the list, modify it and store it back into the list using the list's index-set operator.

I know you know about `List.filled`, but just for other readers, I'll give the one-liner to create the two-dimensional array initialized to `1` values:

```dart
currentMap = new List.generate(height, (_) => new List.filled(width, 1));
```

Comment: Okay, so let's see if I have this right: primitive types are pass-by-value, and objects are pass-by-reference. In my forEach, I AM creating a list for each element because the lists are objects so passed by reference, but the inner loop is not modifying the values since they are ints. Does that sound right? I really appreciate your response by the way; it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: There is no pass-by-value in Dart only pass-by-reference. But you do not have the reference in the list that points to the value, e is a copy of the reference. You can assign a new value to e, but that doesn't affect the list.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments. Could you explain what you mean by "reference"? When I hear that I think something akin to pointers, so I'm thinking that the original would be modified but clearly that is not the case.

Comment: All values in dart are objects, there is no "primitive types" that are not objects - everything has methods, even integers. Dart is "pass-by-(object-)sharing" - which basically means "pass-by-value where values are object references". It is exactly the same as Java and JavaScript. You will find threads discussing what it's called, but the behavior is clear (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference). It is not what is traditionally called "pass-by-reference", where you pass references to *variables*, which can then be modified from the called function.

Comment: It is not because the values are ints that modifying 'e' doesn't change the content of the list. It is because `e` is just a variable, it does not correspond to an entry of the list. It's merely, temporarily, bound to the same value as a list entry. Changing the value of `e` doesn't change anything else. No more than if you did: `var z = e; z = newValue;`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `e` is only a reference to the `List` in `currentMap` not to a `currentMap` item.
You update a copy of the reference to a `List`, but this reference has no connection to `currentMap`.
After the loop, `e` just gets garbage collected.

Comment: If that is the case then why does this statement work?
    e = new List<int>(width);

I understand that f is just a copied value but it does seem as though I can modify the value of e. Thanks for the response!

Comment: As lrn wrote. e and f are local variables that are initialized with a value that points to a list item. You can reassign to them what you want (the analyzer shouts error if the type doesn't fit though) but it doesn't change to which value the list item points to.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and I think I was mistaken in saying the statement affected the list. I'll have to play around with this when I get a chance. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Glad I could help - was also some practice in english because it was not so easy to explain ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how an Enumerator works and I believe because the Enumerator is immutable You can't modify the collection items when it's being processed in a foreach... removing members and such.

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

[What is the best way to modify a list in a 'foreach' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759966/c-sharp-what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-a-list-in-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and for the links. I've found this line in Dart's API docs for Iterable<E>:

"It is generally not allowed to modify such collections while they are being iterated."

Which does not explain why it let me do it in the first place, but does explain that maybe it wasn't a great idea to try to do in the first place.