# Can't remove item from list in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a Flappy Bird clone as an exercise, for I've recently started programming on XNA and I'm stuck on this error that I cannot understand.

I included the following code inside the Update() function, which's job is to delete the pipes when they go off screen lest they infinitely move leftwards while more are created:

```
//Pipe despawner
foreach (var pipe in pipes)
{
   if (pipe.position1.X <= -180)
   {
         pipes.Remove(pipe);
   }
}
```

The game runs fine until the first pipe goes offscreen and the debugger pauses and signals this part of the code with the following message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración.
```

I'm sorry the second part is in spanish, it's my system's language, but hopefully you know how to solve the problem anyway.

I believe I could simply not include this part of the code, given the simplicity of the game and, by consequence, the small toll that infinitely spawning pipes take on performance, but I'd rather not adopt this practice as soon as I start learning game programming.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759966/c-sharp-what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-a-list-in-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the collection (by removing a pipe) while enumerating the collection. This will *always* throw an exception in .NET (and is something to be mindful of if you ever do this in a multi-threaded environment, since you can get some nastily non-reproducible exceptions because of it).

An easy way to solve it is to just keep a "kill" list while enumerating:

List killList = new List();

```
foreach (var pipe in pipes)
{
   if (pipe.position1.X <= -180)
   {
      killList.Add(pipe)
   }
}
```

Even easier:

```
IEnumerable<Pipe> killList = pipes.Where (p => p.position1.X < -100);
```

Either way, enumerate over this *new* collection, and remove matching elements from the main one (thus avoiding the error condition):

```
foreach (Pipe p in killList)
   pipes.Remove(p);
```

And you are done! Again, be mindful of threads. If you are creating new pipes in another thread, you could easily "collide" with this one and cause the exception. If that is the case, make sure to put locks around these sections of code.

Note, you could actually inline "killList" if you use the LINQ method:

```
foreach (Pipe p in pipes.Where(p => p.Position1.X <= -100))
   pipes.Remove(p);
```

As @rot13 suggested, you could also just run RemoveAll, passing it the predicate from the "Where" statement like:

```
pipes.RemoveAll(p => p.Position1.X <= -100);
```

That's about as simple as it gets :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir, perfect explanation and perfect solution!

Comment: You can get rid of the loop from your examples by using the RemoveAll extension method like this: `pipes.RemoveAll(item => item.position1 <= -100);`. You can also enumerate the elements in reverse, then removing one of them won't throw an exception.

Comment: @rot13 Thanks! I included your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove an item from the collection you're currently iterating on with `foreach`.

Either use a `for` loop and adjust the indexes yourself, or use a second collection to handle the pipes you want to delete :

```
List<Pipe> piesToRemove = new List<Pipe>();
// First you flag every pipes you need to remove
foreach (var pipe in pipes)
{
   if (pipe.position1.X <= -180)
   {
         pipesToRemove.Add(pipe);
   }
}

//Now you remove them from your original collection
foreach (var pipe in pipesToRemove)
{
    pipes.Remove(pipe);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than removing the pipes, you may want to simply move them to the other side of the screen and move them up/down.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same.  He can make a small list and just move the ones that are out of the screen.

Comment: This is definitely a more performant approach, and would be a good idea for the OP to consider, especially as the number of "recycled" objects per time unit increases.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying you cannot modify pipes while looping through it. Try something like this:

```
        //Pipe despawner
        var unusedPipes = new List<Pipe>();

        foreach (var pipe in pipes)
        {
            if (pipe.position1.X <= -180)
            {
                unusedPipes.Add(pipe);
            }
        }

        foreach (var unusedPipe in unusedPipes)
        {
            pipes.Remove(unusedPipe);
        }
```

I just took a guess that pipes is a list of pipes.

Comment: The "remove" is going to have a problem (variable out of scope). You would need to enumerate the unusedPipes collection (as in the other answers).

Comment: Yes, also the RemoveAll diddn't work as I assumed. Updated answer, thanks have an upvote on me :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are perfectly valid and will resolve your issue.

However, I think you should be aware that you don't need to create a second collection just to remove an object during iteration.

We can use **reverse iteration** to remove an object from your collection. Try the following:

```
foreach (Pipe pipe in pipes.Reverse<Pipe>())
{
    pipes.Remove(pipe);
}
```

The above code makes the assumption that your collection is a generic List:

```
List<Pipe> pipes = new List<Pipe>();
```

**Edit**

Here is a sample from the game I'm currently working on:

```
private List<Debris> listOfDebris = new List<Debris>();

foreach (Debris debris in listOfDebris.Reverse<Debris>())
{
    CalculateDebrisLocation(debris);

    // Remove debris if it travels outside level boundries
    if (!debris.Rect.Intersects(currentLevel.MapRect))
        listOfDebris.Remove(debris);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? All the other examples of reverse iteration I could find are using a for loop (not a foreach) when they do this, and foreach gets REALLY upset when you do a remove/add inside of it.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure! I've edited my answer to show you one of the cases where I've used reverse iteration. Let me know if you think there is anything wrong with it (works perfectly well as far as I can tell!)

Comment: If you have a working sample, I believe you :). Always glad to learn something new, +1!