# C# List insert in foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, insert

I have the following loop:

```
List<Reminders> reminds = new List<Reminders>();
//...
foreach (Reminders remind in reminds)
{
    //....
    reminds.Insert(id, new Reminders() { Title = remind.Title, Content = remind.Content, Checked = true });
}
```

However, an error occurs in the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (Reminders remind in reminds)
```

If I remove the `reminds.Insert` statement, the error no longer occurs. I'm trying to update some entires inside of the `foreach` loop. What's causing the error?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: your can't modify a collection while iterating over it using `foreach`, what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759966/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-a-list-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: you should use a for() loop instead of foreach...

Comment: why you don't use Add method. Do you need to insert the elements in an specific order?

Comment: I don't need to use an insert if you can update specific entries in a different way .

Comment: Lets first we understand what you want to do to update something in your collection or to insert NEW item in the collection.

Comment: If it did work your loop would run forever because for each iteration you list gets one item loner. Why are you inserting a record for every record in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update some entries then you shoudn't add new ones just set the property `Checked` to `true` of each entry:

```
List<Reminders> reminds = new List<Reminders>();
...
foreach (Reminders remind in reminds)
{
    ....
    remind.Checked = true;
}
```

You must not modify the list that you are iterating.

Comment: thanks! I didn't think it was that simple.

Answer (score 5):

Change your Code to this:

```
List<Reminders> reminds = new List<Reminders>();
...
foreach (Reminders remind in reminds.ToList())
{
    ....
    reminds.Insert(id, new Reminders() { Title = remind.Title, Content = remind.Content, Checked = true });
}
```

Please note the .ToList() behind reminds.

Explanation: You are not allowed to modify a collection while it is enumerated in an foreach. The .ToList() will create **another** temporary collection which will be constrant during the foreach loop.

Comment: While this could have memory and performance implications, if you have a reasonable idea of your list size then it's rather clever. Not sure if a junior programmer is going to see the nuance though.

Answer (score 3):

It's true, you are iterating in the same list. You need to create a temporary list, and add the elements in that temp list in the cycle. After, when the foreach finish, you need to use the method AddRange:

```
reminds.AddRange(tempList);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't insert into an item while iterating through it. Your results will be wrong.
You will need to create a temporary list and do an AddRange() after.