# Working & Modifying Data In Foreach Cycle? C#

Tags: c#, foreach

Lets say I have the following string:

```
  string str = "aaa123aaa";
```

And I convert the given string to char array:

```
 char[] array1 = str.ToArray();
```

Then I want to use foreach to loop through the elements to change all numbers to whitespace

```
foreach (char i in array1)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(i)) { //   ? }
        }
```

How exactly do I change the character matching the criteria to whitespace?
I've tried the following to no avail:

```
i = ' '; char(i) = ' '; array1(i) = ' ';
```

None of them work.

How exactly do I interact with the elements in foreach loop?
It's simple if I use array, in that case I would simply use:

```
array1[i] = ' ';
```

But I've no idea how to do the same in foreach loop.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't want `foreach` which is designed for read-only applications, you want to use a normal `for` loop.

Comment: use a for loop if you want to modify your collection within

Comment: Note that while it is very similar to [modify collection in foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759966/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-a-list-in-a-foreach-loop) it is likely different as OP needs a way to get from item during iteration back to element of collection. Clearly modifying collection in most cases would hit "collection modified" exception as covered in link above..

Answer (score 8):

you can't change the elements of a collection if a `foreach` loop - but you can with a `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(array1[i])) { array1[i] = ' ' }
}
```

Note that this does *not* change the original string - if you want to do that, there are more effective ways that converting to a `char` array.

Comment: In a sense, yes - `foreach` gives you each _item_ from a collection (and any attempts to modify the collection within the loop usually generate an exception)

Comment: @dontseeverysharp - That's a pretty universal concept:  You can't change the item you're enumerating through while you're enumerating it.  Sometimes it won't work, sometimes it will throw an exception.  That's why the integer increment loop works - you never use the enumerator of the array you're modifying.

Comment: "can't change the elements of collection" is not completely true - you can easily change array elements (as it does not have protection against changing element unlike `List<T>`), but `foreach` does not really give you index of item to change - so `for` solves both - get index and safe update irrespective of collection type.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using a `for` loop instead or you can also use LINQ

```
char[] array1 = str.Select(x => char.IsNumber(x) ? ' ' : x).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain what the operator "=>" is called?

Comment: @dontseeverysharp it is used to create a lambda expression. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you replacement is simple, why not use the .NET Regex class and replace the numbers based on the pattern?

```
string test = "aaa123aaa";
test = Regex.Replace(test, "[0-9]", " ");
```