# MVC inserting values into a ViewModel after Model to ViewModel mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, oledb, viewmodel

I am working with two different databases. I am passing the Model collection (SQL Server) to a ViewModel collection. The ViewModel has extra properties which I access out of a Visual Fox Pro database. I am able to map the existing properties, but the ViewModel does not save the data after passing the values to it.

The `WoCust` and the `Lname` fields return `null`, but the rest of the properties which come from the original Model pass to the properties in the ViewModel fine.

When I debug at the `rdr` for the `OleDbCommand`, it shows that the ViewModel is receiving a value for both `rdr[WoCust]` and `rdr[Lname]`.

How do I make it so the ViewModel saves the new values?

WOSchedule.cs...

```cs
public partial class WOSchedule
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string WoNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> QuoteTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PriorityNo { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> WoDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> QuoteID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> WoDone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> WOScheduleListId { get; set; }
    public string StorageLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual QuoteType QuoteType { get; set; }
    public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }
    public virtual WOScheduleList WOScheduleList { get; set; }
}
```

WoWcheduleVM.cs...

```cs
public partial class WoScheduleVM
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string WoNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> QuoteTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PriorityNo { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WoDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> QuoteID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WoDone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> WOScheduleListId { get; set; }
    public string StorageLocation { get; set; }

    public string WoCust { get; set; } // extra property
    public string Lname { get; set; } // extra property

    public virtual QuoteType QuoteType { get; set; }
    public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }
    public virtual WOScheduleList WOScheduleList { get; set; }
}
```

WOSchedulesController.cs

```cs
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foxproTables"].ConnectionString;
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
var wOSchedules = db.WOSchedules.Where(w => w.WoDone == null).Include(w => w.QuoteType);

var wOSchedulesVM = wOSchedules.Select(s => new ViewModels.WoScheduleVM()
  {
     Id = s.Id,
     WoNo = s.WoNo,
     QuoteTypeId = s.QuoteTypeId,
     PriorityNo = s.PriorityNo,
     Active = s.Active,
     WoDate = s.WoDate,
     QuoteID = s.QuoteID,
     WoDone = s.WoDone,
     WOScheduleListId = s.WOScheduleListId,
     StorageLocation = s.StorageLocation
   });

cn.Open();
foreach (var sch in wOSchedulesVM)
  {
    string conn = @"SELECT wo_cust, lname FROM womast INNER JOIN custmast ON womast.wo_cust = custmast.cust_id WHERE wo_no = '" + sch.WoNo + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmdWO = new OleDbCommand(conn, cn);
    OleDbDataReader rdr = cmdWO.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
      sch.WoCust = ((string)rdr["wo_cust"]).Trim();
      sch.Lname = ((string)rdr["lname"]).Trim();
    }
  }
cn.Close();

return View(wOSchedulesVM.OrderByDescending(d => d.WoDate).ToList());
```

Comment: Your code seems ok. When debugging inside `while` statement, quickwatch `rdr["wo_cust"]`, check if is `null` or have value.

Comment: I did do a watch/debug in that area, and It shows a value being returned from the reader (`rdr`). I put a breakpoint at the end of the while (`}`) and saw that the record for `sch` had a value. This is why I am so confused.

Comment: add `rdr.Close()` after the end of the `while`

Comment: Other thoughts, query may be not returning results

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loop for iterating `wOSchedulesVM` collection, which renders the source collection immutable during iteration. The [older documentation version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ttw7t8t6) explicitly explains that behavior:

> The `foreach` statement is used to iterate through the collection to get
>   the information that you want, but **can not be used to add or remove
>   items from the source collection** to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.

Therefore, you should use `for` loop to be able to modify property values inside that collection, as shown in example below:

```
using (var OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(cs))
{
    cn.Open();
    string cmd = @"SELECT wo_cust, lname FROM womast INNER JOIN custmast ON womast.wo_cust = custmast.cust_id WHERE wo_no = @WoNo";

    // not sure if it's 'Count' property or 'Count()' method, depending on collection type
    for (int i = 0; i < wOSchedulesVM.Count; i++)
    {
        var sch = wOSchedulesVM[i];
        using (OleDbCommand cmdWO = new OleDbCommand(conn, cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WoNo", sch.WoNo)
            OleDbDataReader rdr = cmdWO.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    sch.WoCust = (!rdr.IsDbNull(0)) ? rdr.GetString(0).Trim() : string.Empty;
                    sch.Lname = (!rdr.IsDbNull(1)) ? rdr.GetString(1).Trim() : string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This example includes 3 additional aspects, i.e. parameterized query, checking row existence with `HasRows` property and checking against `DBNull.Value` with `IsDbNull()`.

Related issue: [What is the best way to modify a list in a 'foreach' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759966/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-a-list-in-a-foreach-loop)