# Adding values in List<IEnumerable<T>> inside foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, collections

what I want to do is to add for example class in IEnumerable after specific check

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GroupBy<T, O> (this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, O> filter)
    {
        List<IEnumerable<T>> grouped = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            foreach (var g in grouped)
            {
                foreach (var p in g)
                {
                    if (filter(p).Equals(filter(item)))
                    {
                        // Add item to g
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is something like this possible in foreach?

Comment: You should check the `GroupBy` operator from *Linq*, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: Its unclear what you want to do here. Could you include an example?

Comment: Jon Skeet has an entire blog where he implements Linq methods, including [GroupBy](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/)

Comment: You are looping over the contents of `grouped` which has 0 items because you just initialized it, and you added nothing to it. The loop `foreach (var g in grouped)` as you wrote it will do **nothing**, it just exits, regardless of what you wrote inside of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to modify a list in a 'foreach' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759966/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-a-list-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible: every time you change source collection, `foreach` has to be started anew. You'll need to have a separate collection for intermediate accumulation, then join that collection with `grouped`.

Also, your algorithms doesn't work correctly: the second `foreach` will never start working as on the first iteration there will be no items in `grouped` collection. So you will just iterate `list` without applying any logic to its elements.

Comment: Thanks, for answer. Yes i know at first its cleat list but i want to add elements to it and be able to group them. Basicly I'm trying to write GroupBy from Linq by myself. Now I understand its not possible as enumerator changes. Will try different algorithm.